# GCP VM with Nvidia-GPU performance lower than local machine

Tags: gpu, nvidia, torch

Recently I deploy my application to GCP VM and found the performance of GCP VM lower than my local machine.

The same image file (including tensor flow deep learning algorithm), the same Nvidia T4 GPU, why the performance of the GCP VM is so much slower than local machinel.
Through jmeter pressure test (excluding network delay), the average deep learning algorithm response time is GCP VM (1.2s) vs. local (0.7s).

Observe the GPU utilization hrough Nvidia-smi, GCP VM (GPU-Util average less than 50%) vs. ground (GPU-Util average greater than 50%) during the stress test.

Does anyone know how to let GCP GPU speed up?